# Javascript date object UTC instead of user timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am trying to collect input from a user and pass it to a server in order to query for available results in the database.  My issue is that because there is a time input, the timezone effects the query and is returning null, e.g. 6/1/21 = 1622505600000, but 6/1/21 at user timezone might be 1622527200000.

I have parsed the input from the react native frontend using the following code

```
console.log(new Date(selectedDate.getUTCFullYear(), (selectedDate.getUTCMonth()), (selectedDate.getUTCDate()),0,0,0,0))
```

the output of which in this example is
2021-06-01T06:00:00.000Z

Why is the 6 hour delay being added despite the fact that I'm setting all 0 hr, min, sec, ms?

Comment: Because dates still have a TZ; you're just making a new one, and you're UTC+6?

Comment: How is `selectedDate` created? Am I right in assume that you expect the user to input date/time in UTC but due to how things are implemented you end with that date being represented in local timezone? Please provide more information.

Comment: Thank you @DaveNewton, that is correct.  Spent most of the day trying to figure it out despite it's simplicity.

Comment: IIRC in JS the TZ offset for the number of hours lost to date/time issues is `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, give or take a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The date constructor is working from the local timezone and is taking raw inputs to create the date in the local timezone.  When I was running

```
new Date(2021,5,1,0,0,0,0)
```

it was creating that date in the devices local time, then sending to the server.  what I needed to do was

```
new Date(newDate.getUTCFullYear(), (newDate.getUTCMonth()), (newDate.getUTCDate()),0,0,0,0).getTime() - (newDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```

in order to create the date, THEN take away the timezone offset.

edit: the 60,000 offset isn't the amount of offset, it's to get the minutes into milliseconds for the timecode.  the offset is automatically calculated using the getTimezoneOffset() function.

Comment: You haven't explained how you create `selectedDate`, but if you want the user to select UTC time, use the `setUTC*` methods to create the date. Then you don't need to mess with the timezone.